# How Send text to textarea in webbrowser C#

Tags: c#

This is the textarea. I want to send value there but. There isnt name or id. I couldnt send value.

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 300px;">
    <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%; resize: none; outline: currentcolor none medium; text-align: left; -moz-tab-size: 4;" dir="ltr" class="cke_source cke_reset cke_enable_context_menu cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_rtl" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="ویرایش‌گر متن غنی, txtPostContent" title="ویرایش‌گر متن غنی, txtPostContent"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You could give it a name or a id ?   Or loop through all textares's (using [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) and find the textarea that you want to send text to.

Comment: No I can not
This is a blog editor and I do not have access

Comment: use Value proprety.

Comment: This property has no value

Comment: you can not send text to this from c# as this is not server control. From JavaScript you can do.

Comment: I need to send in C # with a web browser

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value of textarea inside the WebBrowser component by executing the below code

```
    //get the main div HTML element by ID
    var cke1ContentsElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("cke_1_contents");
    //from main div select all HTML elements with the tag name "textarea"
    var cke1TextareaList = cke1ContentsElements.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
    //from the selected list of items set value attribute for first element 
    cke1TextareaList[0].SetAttribute("value", "Send This String To TextArea ");
```

[image]

Comment: @Soheil Ghasemi you can set value in this way it works with me, is this solution work with you?

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
Parameter name: index
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Soheil\Desktop\Blog Post Robo\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 86
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)

Comment: @SoheilGhasemi please ensure that URL is fully loaded inside webbrowser component then call the above code

Comment: Fully loaded
I'm sure

Comment: this repository has working sample https://github.com/mhassanshaker/test_browser